# Interromper uma cadeia de ações no SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

Estou desenvolvendo uma simples aplicação com duas telas, uama de autenticação e outra para um segundo processo, esta aplicação é para o IOS usando a linguagem SWIFT.

Ao usar o Storebord para definir as sequências de tela me deparei com a situação onde há duas ações (Eventos) que devem ser executadas, uma se chama "Touch Up Inside" que defini que chame a função abaixo definida como `@IBAction func doLogin(sender: UIButton)` e segunda que prova a sequencia de tela e é uma função interna.

Como sou iniciante na linguagem antes de tentar outra abordagem gostaria de saber como devo proceder para interceptar e evitar a execução da próxima ação (a mudança de tela), caso os dados informados não sejam válidos esta não haverá a transição de tela.

Vou postar abaixo o código que tenho do Controller principal que estou usando para as duas telas, veja que há duas funções a primeira seria a função responsável por cuidar do processo de login (`@IBAction func doLogin(sender: UIButton)`), logo a seguir a este código está o XML que define o storyboard, sendo apenas a parte do botão de login.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Minha Primeira Interface
//
//  Created by Carlos Delfino on 17/09/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Carlos Delfino. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: properties
    @IBOutlet weak var loginTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var consultDocumentButton: UIButton!


    // MARK: unknow
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func doLogin(sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func doConsultDocument(sender: UIButton){

    }


}
```

Abaixo está o XML referente a parte do StoryBoard que define o botão **Login**:

```
...
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fAu-9t-LKt">
   <rect key="frame" x="277" y="503" width="46" height="30"/>
   <size key="titleShadowOffset" width="15" height="11"/>
   <state key="normal" title="Login">
        <color key="titleColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
   </state>
   <variation key="widthClass=compact" fixedFrame="YES">
        <rect key="frame" x="115" y="477" width="170" height="80"/>
   </variation>

   <connections>
        <action selector="doLogin:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="BMZ-tf-EZp"/>
        <segue destination="dEo-UW-BIk" kind="show" id="QdU-ZB-kVG"/>
   </connections>

</button>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você utilizou o próprio `storyboard` para fazer a ligações entre as telas, você precisa tratar a regra no `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`

**SWIFT2**

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if (textField.loginTextField!.characters.count == 0 || textField.passwordTextField!.characters.count == 0) {
        //Aqui você adiciona sua lógica para avisar o usuário
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Caso queira passar algum valor para a próxima tela, você pode usar o `prepareForSegue`

**Obs:** Se você utilizar várias conexões de tela por `storyboard` você precisa verificar qual o identificador no `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` pois senão a regra irá funcionar para todos

Comment: que show hein!!! Obrigado Jeferson.